# Export Mysql to Redis and index with Redis search

Tags: mysql, redis, redis-cli

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE events_all_time (
id int(11) unsigned NOTNULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  action varchar(255) NOTNULL,  count int(11) NOTNULL DEFAULT 0,  PRIMARY KEY (id),  UNIQUE KEY uniq_action (action));
```

Below is an example of an sql script that exports data for redis pipe to read

```
   SELECT CONCAT(
 "*4\r\n",
 '$', LENGTH(redis_cmd), '\r\n',
 redis_cmd, '\r\n',
 '$', LENGTH(redis_key), '\r\n',
 redis_key, '\r\n',
 '$', LENGTH(hkey), '\r\n',
 hkey, '\r\n',
 '$', LENGTH(hval), '\r\n',
 hval, '\r'
)
FROM (
 SELECT
 'HSET' as redis_cmd,
 'events_all_time' AS redis_key,
 action AS hkey,
 count AS hval
 FROM events_all_time
) AS t
```

How can I modify the SQL script to create a schema in Redis with searchable indexes for each column for Redis search?

Then use this command to import to redis using redis-cli pipe.

```
mysql stats_db --skip-column-names --raw < events_to_redis.sql | redis-cli --pipe
```

Comment: Show source table's CREATE TABLE, provide some sample data (2-3 rows) and desired result for this data.

Answer (score 1):

Redis Labs announced their new "RedisCDC" solution at RedisConf 2021 which seamlessly migrates data from heterogeneous data sources to Redis and Redis Modules. It would allow you to avoid manual scripts and complexity outside of what MySQL natively provides.

You can still register for the free virtual conference to watch a RedisCDC deep-dive and demo. Once the conference is over, it will be available on YouTube. Or check this out as a quick overview - https://github.com/RedisLabs-Field-Engineering/RedisCDC